# How to stop awaiting and exit exceution of a function while api calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

Here i have a fuction that update the data

```
async function update() {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post('update', { data: '123' })

       //This response may be delayed
        navigate(previousScreen)

      } catch (error) {
        //handle error
      }
    }
```

Everything works as expected, but the problem is while updating, if i click to other page it goes to the other screen. Then once the update api promise is resolved, then again navigate() is called which is below await.

Sometime while updating if i click logout, it logout and again it navigate.

Is there is any way to stop all awaiting queues?

Comment: No, you can't just stop awaiting. You can try to cancel an async operation but that needs to be supported by the operation you try to cancel. You'll also have to craft your own code to support cancellations. Thus there is no generic "stop async op".

Comment: Do you really want to *stop* the request, though? Whatever POSTing to /update does, seems like it might  be important. From your description, you just want to avoid the navigation. You could...do that. Or rather *not* do that. If you check whether navigation is appropriate (user is still on the same screen or perhaps user hasn't navigated anywhere), and if not, then don't execute the `navigate()`. What you're trying to solve might be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: What is `navigate`? And where/how are you calling `update()`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if user is still on the same page before navigating:

```
async function update() {
  try {
    const pathBeforeRequest = window.location.pathname;
    const res = await axios.post("update", { data: "123" });

    if (pathBeforeRequest === window.location.pathname) {
      //This response may be delayed
      navigate(previousScreen);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    //handle error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop a Promise once initiated. However, you can prevent the execution of the navigate statement below the await statement when a user has already navigated.

**Step 1:** Setup a flag to track navigation. If a user has not navigated yet and the promise resolves, let the `navigate(previousScreen)` execute. If a user has already navigated, skip the execution.

```
let hasUserNavigated = false;

async function update() {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post('update', { data: '123' })
        
       if(!hasUserNavigated){
        navigate(previousScreen)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        //handle error
      }
    }
```

**Step 2:**
Somewhere else in your code, when you navigate, set the flag to true:

```
hasUserNavigated = true;
```

**Example, let's say we want to navigate to some page after a user clicks on logout.**

```
const handleLogout = () => {
  hasUserNavigated = true;

  //navigate users to some page that you want
}
```

Inside your return portion of your component, set up a button to logout and navigate users:

```
<button 
  onClick={() => handleLogout()}
>
 logout
</button>
```